Can't close window from other thread: "{"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}"
i built a Custom Splash Screen using the BackgroundWorker, everything is working fine until i want to close the Splash Screen window.
I'm getting this error: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."
Basically i want to show the splash screen when loading data and close it after, and show the mainwindow.
here is my code:
BackgroundWorker worker;
Splash_Screen splash;
Thread thread;

this.Hide();
worker = new BackgroundWorker(); //Initializing the worker object
worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork; //Binding Worker_DoWork method
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted; //Binding 
worker_RunWorkerCompleted method
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

//do some works when loading the App and call the RunWorkerCompleted when finished

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted; //Binding worker_RunWorkerCompleted method
this.Show();
this.Activate();

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //Close the thread of the Splash_Screen
  System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(thread).InvokeShutdown();
  splash.Close();
}

private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  StaThreadWrapper(() =>
  {
   splash = new Splash_Screen();
   splash.Show();
  });
}

private void StaThreadWrapper(Action action)
{
  thread = new Thread(o =>
   {
    action();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
   });
   thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   thread.Start();
}

i already searched in other threads here, but didn't find the answer.
Thank you for your help.

Why use a background worker and a separate thread together?

Why the use of the backgroundworker at all? It is a very old thing and it should not be used any more

honestly, it's a code i found when i wanted to make a custom splashscreen and it worked fine on others App i did so i reuse it.

Invoke the close call through the Dispatcher, that will marshal the call to the window's thread

You shouldn't be creating multiple UI threads in the first place.  Use a single UI thread.

After more research i tried to reproduce the same with Task only without BackgroundWorker and it worked.
Here's the code:
Thread newWindowThread;

private void Init()
{
  this.Hide();

  //do some works when loading the App

  this.Show();
  this.Activate();
  Dispatcher.FromThread(newWindowThread).InvokeShutdown();
}

private void Splash()
{
  newWindowThread = new Thread(ThreadStartingPoint);
  newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
  newWindowThread.Start();
}

private void ThreadStartingPoint()
{
  Splash_Screen splash = new Splash_Screen();
  splash.Show();
  Dispatcher.Run();
}

